# resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8

Tags: android-studio

После обновления до Android 3.0 перестал запускаться эмулятор.
Emulator: ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8

Переустановил эмулятор и haxm с максимальным допустимым размером.
При повторном запуске эмулятора в offline выдает:
Instant Run is not supported on devices with API levels 20 or lower

Есть идеи?